Questions about multiplication and division properties of rounding down
I have  questions about the floor.

With ccs in $[0,1]$ and $y$ in $[0.5,1]$, can the following expression be seen as approximating 2^63*ccs*y$$\left \lfloor\frac{\left \lfloor  2^{63}  * ccs \right \rfloor *y * 2^{63}  }{2^{63}} \right \rfloor$$

Or I can abstract the problem, $a,b$ is a real number, and $c$` is an integer $$\left \lfloor \frac{\left \lfloor a \right \rfloor *b }{c}  \right \rfloor  = \left \lfloor \frac {a*b}{c}  \right \rfloor  $$
When does the above equation hold



A number can't be between an interval, it can be in that interval or between the endpoints.

Thank you for reminding me

I'm going to assume this is about exact arithmetic for nonnegative real numbers.  In that case:
$$ \frac{\left \lfloor  2^{63}  * ccs \right \rfloor *y * 2^{63}  }{2^{63}} 
= \left \lfloor  2^{63}  * ccs \right \rfloor *y $$
and the first part of your Question asks if this "approximates" the latter expression without the floor function, $2^{63}  * ccs * y$.
Since $\left \lfloor  2^{63}  * ccs \right \rfloor$ and $2^{63}  * ccs$ differ by less than $1$ (but the difference can approach $1$ as closely as we please in real arithmetic), all we can say is that:
$$ 0 \le (2^{63}  * ccs * y) - (\left \lfloor  2^{63}  * ccs \right \rfloor *y) \lt y $$
For example, if $2^{63}  * ccs = 1.999$, then the difference is $0.999 y$.  However if one applies the floor function to the difference, using $y \in [0.5,1]$, then the floor of the difference is zero (since the difference is in $[0,1)$.

Thank you for your help. I'm still confused.  Why is it possible to simplify $$\left \lfloor \frac{\left \lfloor 2^{63}* ccs \right \rfloor y 2^{63}}{2^{63}}  \right \rfloor $$ to $$\left \lfloor 2^{63} ccs \right \rfloory  $$?Shouldn't the result of the simplification be $$\left \lfloor \left \lfloor 2^{63}* ccs \right \rfloor*y   \right \rfloor $$?

No, I just simplified the "insides" of that expression (omitting the outer floor).
